# Mask an array with conditions on multiple columns

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am working with a NxMx3 array which is actually a RGB image of size NxM. I want to mask some of the pixels in this image using the condition that the pixels must be different from a known color. I don't want to rely on external image manipulation libraries, so I tried numpy masked array and similar, without much success for the moment.

I wish I could write something like:

```
A = np.array([[[255,0,255],[0,255,0]],[[128,0,128],[0,128,0]]]) # 2x2x3
mask = A[:,:] != np.array([0, 255, 0]) # Mask green pixel
```

but this piece of code doesn't work as *I* expected because it partially masks elements I want to keep (the `0`s in `[0,128,0]` are masked too here). I tried a lot of different things, most of them did not even run because of dimensions mismatch but here is the shortest *non*-working example I found!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first compare `A` with `(0, 255, 0)` to obtain a boolean mask of shape (2,2,3). It is True when the channel value equals the corresponding value in the [broadcasted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) tuple:

```
In [26]: A != (0, 255, 0)
Out[26]: 
array([[[ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [False,  True, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

Since broadcasting adds new axes on the left as needed, the tuple gets broadcasted to an array of shape (1,1,3) and then further broadcasted to shape (2,2,3) upon comparison with `A`. Thus the component values in the tuple get compared with just the right the corresponding component values in `A`.

Now to obtain a boolean mask of shape (2,2) which is True when all the channel components are equal to the tuple for a given pixel, use `any`:

```
In [27]: (A != (0, 255, 0)).any(axis=2)
Out[27]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

`any(axis=2)` reduces the boolean array of shape (2,2,3) along the last axis. The result is True if *any* of the values along that last axis is True.

Comment: Great, thank you! I wonder when I will know everything that must be known about broadcasting in Numpy... Meanwhile, I had another -- but ugly -- solution: `(A[:,:,0] == 0) & (A[:,:,1] == 255) & (A[:,:,2] == 0)` but yours is clearly more elegant.